# Data List pagination primefaces mobile 5.2 not working

Tags: primefaces, pagination, primefaces-mobile

The pagination of my datalist is not working on primefaces mobile, it shows 1000 rows instead of 5! I changed my pf version from 5.1 to 5.2 and nothing happened. I checked the showcase and read the pf 5.2 guide and I don't find the solution. Here my code :

listPromotion.xhtml

```
<ui:composition 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
>
<pm:header title="Vos promotions"></pm:header>
<pm:content>

    <h:form id="form2">
        <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">                
            <p:dataList value="#{partnerListPromotion.promotions}" 
                        var="promotion" 
                        pt:data-inset="true" 
                        paginator="true" 
                        rows="5">                   
                <p:commandLink 
                     action="#{partnerListPromotion.
                               goToPartnerDetailPromotion(promotion)}"/>                        
                </p:dataList>  
        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
</pm:content>
```

**index.xhtml** Note that dev.xtml is just a way to access to listPromotion.xhtml.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<f:view renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE" />
<h:head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/geolocalisationPartner.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/refreshTimePromotion.js"></script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <!-- dev -->
    <pm:page id="dev" lazy ="false">
        <ui:include src="trash/dev.xhtml"/>
    </pm:page>
    <pm:page id="partnerListPromotion" lazy="true">
        <ui:include src="/Partner/listPromotion.xhtml"/>
    </pm:page>
</h:body>
```

My maven **pom.xml** :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I just spot this on my glassfish log : "Infos:   Running on PrimeFaces 5.1
Infos:   Running on PrimeFaces 5.1" , so I gonna try to force primefaces 5.2 and then go back to this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was glassfish still used primefaces 5.1 even if I put primefaces 5.2 in my pom.xml. So I had to remove all the primefaces folder in the maven repository in my home : .m2/repository/org/primefaces except 5.2. Then Glassfish used 5.2 and pagination worked !